# I can't copy a file in its own directory

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-management

When I'm working on modifying files, I prefer to take a copy first and to work on that copy. When I see everything is OK, then I delete the original file and replace it by the copy I've been working on, in summary:

```
<filename>.<extention> => Copy/Paste
<filename>_Copy.<extension> (result of the paste)
```

Now when I try to do this with a *.htm file, this seems not to be possible (I get the complaint that source and destination files are equal).

How can I get rid of this error message and have *.htm files treated just like all other files on my computer? Seen the first comments on this post there should be some configuration setting taking care of this.

Comment: I tried to reproduced this problem in my system and it didn't reproduce. New Text Document.html simply got copied into New Text Document - Copy.html. No error or anomally occurred.

Comment: @FleetCommand did you try .ht**m**, not .htm**l**?

Comment: Yes. I knew you'd ask that.

Comment: What if you rename that file in question to something else say .txt (temporarily) and try to do a copy-paste in the same folder, does it still fail or process successfully? What if you copy that .htm file to some other folder on another drive/partition and try to do copy-paste, does it fail again?

Comment: @pat2015: you might have stumbled upon something: when I tried to rename it (to a *.txt) file, I saw an error message, saying "If you rename this file, it will no longer belong to the folder '<foldername>'. ...". This seems to mean that Windows keeps pairs of web pages and folders, and as such, thinks that this file belongs to a particular folder (although this is not the case). Now I just need to know how I can disable the link between web pages and folders in Windows 10.

Comment: The .htm file that you are trying to copy is most likely a part of saved Web Page as Complete. This includes htm file and associated supporting files like css, js, jpg, gif etc etc in a folder that all form complete web page. Check if you have a folder by the same name therein same as htm file. Open that .htm in your web browser and then save as complete with another name. Still idealy it should not give that error when you just do a copy-paste within